# Creating a sequence of distinct random numbers within a certain range in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file which contains entries numbered 0 to 149. I am writing a bash script which randomly selects 15 out of these 150 entries and create another file from them.
I tried using random number generator:

```
var=$RANDOM
var=$[ $var % 150 ]
```

Using var I picked those 15 entries. But I want all of these entries to be different. Sometimes same entry is getting picked up twice. Is there a way to create a sequence of random numbers within a certain range, (in my example, 0-149) ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`shuf -i`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=shuf+-i+0-149+-n+15) to generate a random list of numbers.

```
$ entries=($(shuf -i 0-149 -n 15))
$ echo "${entries[@]}"
55 96 80 109 46 58 135 29 64 97 93 26 28 116 0
```

If you want them in order then add [`sort -n`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=shuf+-i+0-149+-n+15+%7C+sort+-n) to the mix.

```
$ entries=($(shuf -i 0-149 -n 15 | sort -n))
$ echo "${entries[@]}"
12 22 45 49 54 66 78 79 83 93 118 119 124 140 147
```

To loop over the values, do:

```
for entry in "${entries[@]}"; do
    echo "$entry"
done
```

Comment: What does the [@] mean in ${entries[@]? Say I wanted to run a loop on these values , can i do : for i in $entries do ... done  ?

Comment: OSX users: installable via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/): `brew install coreutils`; invoke as `gshuf`.

Comment: @user3286661 [@] expands to 'all items in array' - if you do 'echo $entries' you will get the first item. If you do 'echo ${entries[@]}' it will echo all items.

Comment: I can't get it to provide any more than 1001 numbers. CentOS 64 bit. Is that expected?